# Should I say 'find...interesting' or 'find...to be interesting'?

Tags: transitivity, infinitive-phrases

In the sentence

> I find Area 51 interesting because there is so little information about it.

Shall I add 'to be' before 'interesting'?

Comment: The *to be* is completely unnecessary as it doesn't really add any useful meaning. It's best to leave it out and just go for the construction *find...interesting*.

Comment: What about ' I find ... particularly interesting'? Will it sound more smooth if I say ' I find... to be particularly intersting'?

Comment: Again, the *to be* is unnecessary. You could simply say '*I find ... particularly interesting.*', which sounds more idiomatic.

Comment: Unnecessary, but you may say "find it to be....".   It is idiomatic.

Comment: *I think it **to be** a "subjunctive" construction*, which native speakers in general increasingly tend to avoid - they're much more likely to say *they think it **is** subjunctive* (if they know what "subjunctive" means, and if they agree with me! :) Or discard the "helper" verb completely, since it's usually not required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following sentences are from MW Learners Dictionary:

1. I found him (to be) a sensible man.
2. Students often find this book (to be) useful.

The Dictionary has put the "to be" in parenthesis, which indicates that it's optional to use the "to be".

So you can  either put "to be" in front of the adjective interesting in the OP's sentence or leave it out, without any difference in meaning.  However, the structure of a sentence with the verb find + object + adjective is more common than that of find + object + to be + adjective.

Answer (score 3):

"To be" or not "to be", that is the question. . .

They are both grammatically acceptable. The use of the phrase "to be" in this case sounds more formal and a little archaic, which is probably why I prefer it, but the construction without "to be" is far more common, at least in American English.